# How do I change background and zoom settings in Spline Scene

Tags: javascript, animation, spline

I want to use this scene in my HTML, but I need to change some of the scene settings - like background, disable zoom etc.

How do I duplicate published scene to my draft?

https://my.spline.design/interactivespherescopy-d9d1c8bb2f660546855bd1b02c7063f8/

I tried to apply this scene as it is but I can't change background or zoom settings via JavaScript